# How to add anchor tag in data table based conditon

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am displaying one of my data base table using data table jQuery plug-in in jsp.

[image]

In this table I have project code & status columns.

Now what I need is when I click on project code link, it should forward to that particular anchor tag link based on status.

For example 1st row status is Pending survey. For this status when I click on project code link I need forward to proceed to survey jsp page page.

For 2nd row status BQ Prepared. For this status when I click on project code link I need forward to that corresponding jsp jsp.

This is my jsp code

```
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Created On</th>
                    <th>Project Code</th>
                    <th>Adjuster</th>
                    <th>Owner</th>
                    <th>Assigned To</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <%
              for(int i=0;i<joborderlist.size();i++){
                %>
                <div>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%></td>
                        <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getJobCreatesOnasString()%></td>
                        <td><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px solid black;"><%=joborderlist.get(i).getCaseNo()%></a></td>
                        <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getAdjustername()%></td>
                        <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getOwnername()%></td>
                        <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getMarketing()%>,<br>
                            <%=joborderlist.get(i).getQs()%>
                       </td>
                       <td><%=joborderlist.get(i).getStatus()%></td>
                       <td><a href="createjoborder.jsp?id=<%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%>&viewjoborder=View" class="urlImg" style="margin-left: 129px;" title="View"><!-- <abbr title="View"><img alt="" src="images/view.png"></abbr> --></a>
                        <a href="createjoborder.jsp?id=<%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%>&updatejoborder=Update" class="urlImgUpdate" style="margin-left: 93px;" title="Update"><!-- <abbr title="Update"><img alt="" src="images/update.png"></abbr> --></a>
                        <a href="../CreateJobOrder?id=<%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%>&deletejoborder=Delete" class="urlImgDelete" style="margin-left: 161px;" title="Delete"><!-- <abbr title="Delete"><img alt="" src="images/Remove.png"></abbr> --></a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </div>
                <%}%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to process the `click` event of the `anchor` tag & depending on the `status` of that row, redirect the user to respective location.

Add some class selector for anchor tag & for status tag,then attach a event handler for `click` event (`Delegated event`). **prevent the default behaviour of the anchor element & process the `status` value & redirect the user to respective page .**

**HTML Code:**

```
<td><a class="surveyLink" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px solid black;"><%=joborderlist.get(i).getCaseNo()%></a></td>
<td class="status"><%=joborderlist.get(i).getStatus()%></td>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$('#example').on('click','.surveyLink', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var status = $(this).closest('tr').find('.status').text(); 
     if (status === 'Pending Survey'){
          window.location ='http://...../survey.jsp';
     } else if (status === 'BQ Prepared'){
          window.location ='http://...../processPage.jsp';
     }
     //process other status as well
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since i used Java, but i think your Java code does not cause your problem, i assume it is the following.

You use

```
<td><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px solid black;"><%=joborderlist.get(i).getCaseNo()%></a></td>
```

on the *Project Code* field, the essential thing here is that you use `href="#"` and as this directs you to nowhere. Now on your *Status* field you seem to generate a link and fill your `href` accordingly.

What you need to do is get this exactly link and fill your *Project Code* field instead of the *Status* field.

So you need to select what case your Status is in your JSP, so this is your *Project Code* href:

```
// Get the case with yourStatus() in this example.

href="createjoborder.jsp?id=<%=joborderlist.get(i).getSno()%>&viewjoborder=<%yourStatus()%>"
```